# Edit cells in DataGrid with hidden rows

Tags: wpf, datagrid, cell, visibility, edit

In WPF I have a DataGrid with some Collapsed rows. When I edit a cell and then press enter, if the next row is collapsed then the selection doesn't move to the next visible row. Instead a dotted rectangle surrounds the cell I've just edited and typing the keyboard results in no action at all.
Any idea how I can make the selection jump to the next visible row?
Thank you

Example (under framework 4.0):
The xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfDataGridEdit.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dataGrid">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Value1}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Value2}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Visibility}" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

The code behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfDataGridEdit
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private List<Row> rows = new List<Row>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                this.rows.Add(new Row { Value1 = i.ToString(), Value2 = "x", Visibility = i % 3 == 0 ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible });

            this.dataGrid.ItemsSource = this.rows;
        }
    }

    public class Row
    {
        private string value1;
        public string Value1
        {
            get { return this.value1; }
            set { this.value1 = value; }
        }

        private string value2;
        public string Value2
        {
            get { return this.value2; }
            set { this.value2 = value; }
        }

        private Visibility visibility;
        public Visibility Visibility
        {
            get { return this.visibility; }
            set { this.visibility = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

By editing rows and typing enter you should get stuck in the second row.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your issue when asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Added example of this behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea how I can make the selection jump to the next visible row?

This behaviour has been reported as a bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/526014/keyboard-navigation-doesnt-work-when-the-wpf-datagrid-has-collapsed-or-hidden-rows

You may be able to get around it by handling the PreviewKeyDown event for the DataGrid something like this:

```
private void dataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
        int index = dg.SelectedIndex;
        if (index < dg.Items.Count - 1)
        {
            dg.SelectedIndex++;
            DataGridRow nextRow = dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(dg.SelectedIndex) as DataGridRow;
            while (nextRow != null && nextRow.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
                nextRow = dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(dg.SelectedIndex + 1) as DataGridRow;

            if (nextRow != null)
            {
                dg.SelectedItem = nextRow.DataContext;
                dg.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(nextRow.DataContext, dg.Columns[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** You may also want to save the index of the currently edited column by hooking up an event handler to the `BeginningEdit` event:

```
DataGridColumn _lastEditedColumn;
private void dataGrid_BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
    _lastEditedColumn = dg.CurrentCell.Column;
}
```

..and set the `CurrentCell` to this one:

```
if (nextRow != null)
{
    dg.SelectedItem = nextRow.DataContext;
    dg.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(nextRow.DataContext, _lastEditedColumn); //<---
}
```

Comment: This only works in the example I've given because it has one column. In a multi column datagrid this will result in the focus moved to the right and not below the edited cell.

Comment: That's one of the reason why I asked you to provide a full repo of your issue. Obviously you didn't.

Comment: Also note that this behaviour has been reported as a bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/526014/keyboard-navigation-doesnt-work-when-the-wpf-datagrid-has-collapsed-or-hidden-rows

Comment: That's a different bug although related to hidden rows too.

Comment: Please see my edited answer. It should give you the idea on how you could possibly work around this.

Comment: This reverts to the first column if you start from a different one. I got around that by handling the BeginningEdit and storing the column info  in lastEditedColumn then using that in "dg.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(nextRow.DataContext, dg.Columns[lastEditedColumn]);" if you can fix your reply I'll mark it as a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by mm8 is perfect if you only have one collapsed row to skip over. The code enters an infinite loop when adjacent rows are collapsed.

When getting next row the code should increment selectedIndex instead of adding 1 to the same value.

i.e. replace `dg.SelectedIndex + 1` with `++dg.SelectedIndex`

like this:

```cs
private void dataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
        int index = dg.SelectedIndex;
        if (index < dg.Items.Count - 1)
        {
            dg.SelectedIndex++;
            DataGridRow nextRow = dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(dg.SelectedIndex) as DataGridRow;
            while (nextRow != null && nextRow.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
                nextRow = dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(++dg.SelectedIndex) as DataGridRow;

            if (nextRow != null)
            {
                dg.SelectedItem = nextRow.DataContext;
                dg.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(nextRow.DataContext, dg.Columns[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: By advancing the DataGrid's SelectedIndex to a collapsed row, any SelectedCellsChanged or SelectionChanged events on the DataGrid will fire. This might not be desirable for your application depending on what it does in these events.

If this is the case, you may want to consider using a variable to hold the index like this:

```cs
private void dataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
        int index = dg.SelectedIndex;
        int maxIndex = dg.Items.Count - 1;

        while (index < maxIndex
            && (dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(++index) as DataGridRow)?.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
        {
        }

        if ((dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as DataGridRow)?.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            dg.SelectedIndex = index;
        }
    }
}
```

The empty while loop is deliberate because index is advanced in the condition. (I don't enjoy this code style but it works)

(Background: I tried to submit this correction as an edit to mm8's answer but because it changed the content of the answer the edit was rejected. Because I don't have enough rep to add a comment, per [advice on editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164449), I'm posting the correction as a new answer.)